# When updating my view model why isn't my user control updating?

Tags: wpf, events, button, mvvm, user-controls

I have a tab item where i am currently loading a user control as item in a data template. I have two date pickers and a button. On click of this button i need to show a stack panel which in turn loads other controls. My problem here is though the click event has triggered and new data is available in a new object/ collection, upon assigning that to properties in view model is not updating the control with data. Also i unable to change the visibility of the panel.
Here is the code :

The user control is a data template of tabitem and the tabcontrol itemsource bound to a collection. Since i was getting binding expression error when ever i tried to bind control with properties in my view model directly, what i did is created same properties in model class constructor and there i get/set value for the viewmodel properties. Currently the compiler shows no binding error if i bind properties defined in model class.

```
<UserContrl>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row = "0">
    <Button Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Generate Graph"
            Width="140" Command="{Binding GenGraph}" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row = "1" Visibility={Binding ShowReport">
    ......
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Does your ViewModel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? That interface is required if WPF is to automatically update the UI when properties change. Perhaps you can show us your ViewModel code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Cut and Paste? Because you're missing a closing "}" on your binding...

Answer (score 0):

Are they public properties that implement iNotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the ShowReport property in your viewmodel is of type Visibility (not boolean)
All properties that you bind to in XAML must be available in the ViewModel class , the compiler will not show any error if they are not , also at runtime you will recieve no errors because of this , they just will not work.
Can you show more XAML/code for the other problem (controls inside stackpanel)?
I would be intrested in the view XAML and viewmodel code